# Formula to populate one column based on the values on range of cells - excel

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to populate a column with the value YES, if another range of cells are all populated. If this range of cells aren't populated to have the value NO.

Column A Column B Column C Column D

2fd 6g  4l  7yy Yes

12ex    4l  5aa     No

3kk 4l  6g  No

9q  8m  5aa 6g  Yes

my data contains words and letters.

Comment: Please provide us with your code you actually tried. Btw, this can be done using excel formulas : `=IF(COUNTA(A1:C1)=3;"yes";"no")`

Comment: I have tired the formula and this does not work? could i ask why is there "=3"?. ps havent tired a code yet as not sure if would be If formula or maybe marco?

Comment: You may need to replace the argument separator semicolon `;` for comma `,` (it's based on your and mine local settings) The `=3` is there to check if all the 3 adjacent cells are not empty. Ou, sorry you wanted to check 4 cells. Then `=IF(COUNTA(A1:D1)=4,"yes","no")` - I changed the semicolon to comma in this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(A1:D1)=0;"yes";"no")
```

If none of the cells is blank, it will return "yes". If there is a blank cell, it will return "no".

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(COUNTA(A1:D1)=4,"yes","no")`